# the objects inside a NSMutableDictionary are lost during runtime. the pointers are lost somehow

Tags: iphone, xcode, pointers, nsmutablearray, retain

I have a NSMutableDictionary in a class

```
@interface ClassName : UITableViewController {
        NSMutableArray *doctors_set;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSMutableArray *doctors_set;

@implementation ClassName
@synthesize DocID,doctors_set;
```

I'm adding 4 objects

```
DoctorsSet *set = [[DoctorsSet alloc] init];

//DoctorsSet is an extended NSObject

[doctors_set addObject:set];
```

what I want is to use the sets in the same class (I'm using a tableview) 
so when I tap on the cell I must recover the set on the index tapped

```
DoctorsSet *set = (DoctorsSet *)[doctors_set objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

when the didSelectRowAtIndexPath event occurs.. the sets at the indexes are lost, i can see it in the debugger. the indexes don't even have the DoctorsSet type..they're replace by some random types that tells me that somehow the objects are not retained...
    This happens if I tap 2,3 times on the table cells

when I assign the array in the debugger i get

```
self 
  doctors_set = (_NSARRAYM *) pointerid 4 objects
    0 = (DoctorsSet *) pointerid
    1 = (DoctorsSet *) pointerid
    2 = (DoctorsSet *) pointerid
    3 = (DoctorsSet *) pointerid
```

when I get the error , because it sais that the selector does not belong to the object (that's because the object itself is lost)

```
self 
  doctors_set = (_NSARRAYM *) pointerid 4 objects
    0 = (NSObject *) pointerid
    1 = (NSObject *) pointerid
    2 = (NSCFString *) pointerid
    3 = (UITouchData *) pointerid
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet where you initialize `doctors_set`?

Comment: yes, I'm doing a while when I'm reading each doctor from the db...see my comment on answer 1, I've pasted there the code.. It's bad that I can't format it better on the comments....

Answer (score 0):

Where do you allocate the NSMutableArray and assign it to your doctors_set property? My guess is that you are assigning it without keeping it retained.

You probably want to do something like:

```
doctors_set = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If you show how you allocate and store this property it should be easier to tell how to fix it.

Comment: on the  i've defined a method that gets from the DB all my doctors and interface .... -(void) readDoctorsFromDatabase;  ... @end
implementation
....
-(void) readUsedDoctorsFromDatabase {
 if (doctors_set!=nil) [doctors_set release];
 // Init the doctors_set Array
 doctors_set = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        .........
         while (readdoctorsfromdatabase) { 
           //my custom initializer for the Doctorsset
             DoctorsSet *set = [[DoctorsSet alloc] initCustom:data data];
            [doctors_set addObject:set];
         }
}

Comment: I do call the method readUsedDoctorsFromDatabase on initialize
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self readUsedDoctorsFromDatabase];
}

Comment: You should edit your original post to include this code: It would make it more readable.

Comment: If you are calling this method from viewDidLoad, then you are releasing the doctors_set and reinitializing a new one each time the view is unloaded and reloaded. This is probably not what you want to happen. Keep in mind that a view may be unloaded and reloaded many times as needed during the life cycle of your app

Comment: the array will suffer modifications during the lifetime of the view, for example if I input a filter.. I need to free all the doctors array (is there any other way to do it? rather than call the release?), I have to requery, refill the array and redraw the tableview..

Comment: You should cop your real code as it exists into the original post so we can see it. What you've typed in here is incomplete and invalid. For example, you don't show where readdoctorsfromdatabase is set nor does "initCustomData:data data" make sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3713/discussion-between-tim-dean-and-partysoft)